# Pandas - Generate sequences of consecutive rows (by timestamp) over grouped by values

Tags: python, pandas, data-preprocessing

I am working on an LSTM-based network where I need to model sequences of occurances over other column's values using `Pandas` where each sequence must be limited by length.

A practical usecase for this, I have multiple machines with logs, the logs are marked with a title and a timestamp (for the sake of the example, `t1 < t2 < t3 ...`), the initial dataframe looks like this:

```
d = {'timestamp': ['t1', 't2', 't1', 't3', 't2', 't2', 't1'], 
     'machine': ['M1', 'M2', 'M2', 'M1', 'M2', 'M1', 'M3'], 
     'log': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df.head(7))

  timestamp machine log
0        t1      M1   A
1        t2      M2   B
2        t1      M2   A
3        t3      M1   C
4        t2      M2   A
5        t2      M1   A
6        t1      M3   B
```

What I want to get is a dataframe with sequences of up to size `max_len = 2` for each machine.
The desired output should look like this:

```
max_len = 2

  machine sequence
0      M1   [A, A]  # index from original df: [0, 5]
1      M1   [A, C]  # index from original df: [5, 3]
2      M2   [A, A]  # index from original df: [2, 4]
3      M2   [A, B]  # index from original df: [4, 1]
4      M3      [B]  # index from original df: [6]
```

The sequences are limited by `max_len = 2` and their elements are ordered by `timestamp`.

```
max_len = 3

  machine   sequence
0      M1  [A, A, C]  # index from original df: [0, 5, 3]
1      M2  [A, A, B]  # index from original df: [2, 4, 1]
2      M3        [B]  # index from original df: [6]
```

The sequences are limited by `max_len = 3` and their elements are ordered by `timestamp`.

**Note:** `max_len` parameter is an upper bound for the sequence length, I will pad short sequences (like `M3`'s) to fit LSTM requirements.

**Note 2:** I am actually grouping by 2 columns, but for this example to be as minimum as I can, I only included one column.

**What I tried so far:**

I was using `PySpark` up until now but I did it incorrectly by incrementally using the `F.lag` function. that left many useless partial sequences from which I cannot identify the short sequences that needs padding, also this naive approach is slow and basically not that good.

```
w = Window.repartition('machine').orderBy('timestamp')
for i in range(max_len):
   df = df.withColumn(f"log_lag_{i}", F.lag('log', i-1).over(w))
```

I would appreciate help how to deal with this using `Pandas`, I have been trying for a long time and failed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets Try itertools

```
import itertools
df=(df.assign(log1=df.groupby('machine')['log'].apply(lambda x: list(sorted(i) for i in (itertools.combinations(x, 2))))# get sorted tuple combinations
              .explode()# Explode them into rows
              .reset_index(drop=True)#Drop index
              .combine_first(df['log'])#Update the new column where there is a null value
              .astype(str)#Convert the lists into string
             ).drop_duplicates(subset=['log','log1'])#drop duplicates
             .drop('timestamp',1)#drop column
   )

   machine log        log1
0      M1   A  ['A', 'C']
1      M2   B  ['A', 'A']
3      M1   C  ['A', 'B']
4      M2   A  ['A', 'B']
5      M1   A  ['A', 'A']
6      M3   B           B
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am wondering, you used the `sorted()` method to sort the elements in each sequence, but, I need them to be sorted by `timestamp`, how can this be modified? can a preprocess of `df.sort_values(by=['machine', 'timestamp'])` do the trick?) thanks again!

Comment: Did you mean `df=(df.assign(log1=df.groupby('machine')['log'].apply(lambda x: list(sorted(i) for i in (itertools.combinations(x, 2))))# get sorted tuple combinations
              .explode()# Explode them into rows
              .reset_index(drop=True)#Drop index
              .combine_first(df['log'])#Update the new column where there is a null value
              .astype(str)#Convert the lists into string
             ).drop_duplicates(subset=['log','log1'])#drop duplicates
             .drop('timestamp',1)#drop column
   ).sort_values(['machine', 'log', 'log1'])`

Comment: I meant `df.sort_values(by=['machine', 'timestamp']).assign(...` because the `sorted` method you used in the `apply` call will only sort the logs defaultly, I need the logs to be sorted by `timestamp`.

Comment: Are you after `df=(df.sort_values(by =['timestamp'], ascending=False).assign(log1=df.groupby('machine')['log'].apply(lambda x: list(sorted(i) for i in (itertools.combinations(x, 2))))# get sorted tuple combinations
              .explode()# Explode them into rows
              .reset_index(drop=True)#Drop index
              .combine_first(df['log'])#Update the new column where there is a null value
              .astype(str)#Convert the lists into string
             ).drop_duplicates(subset=['log','log1'])#drop duplicates
              .drop('timestamp',1)
   )`

Comment: Thank you very much, a little bit of midification to fit my dataset and your solution worked like a charm, thanks again!